# Why am I unable to create this procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I just wanted to thank you all for your great help so far. I have another challenge for you guys and I've been dealing with it trying to get it to work but I might've exhausted myself on this one. I'm a new SQL student learning so cut me some slack if needed.

The goal is to create a procedure that will take update the grade for someone by giving the student id, class, and the letter grade.

Here's what I have

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AssignGradeToStudent
    @[Class Number] char,
    @student int,
    @Grade char,
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Enrollment
    SET [Grade] = COALESCE(@Grade,[Grade]) 
    WHERE [Class Number] = [Class Number]
      AND [Student] = Student  
END
```

Comment: Why the COALESCE? I mean the 'job' of the stored proc is to update the grade, why would you even call it if you don't provide a value for the @Grade parameter?

Comment: Do you get any error? If Yes what's that?

Comment: You should **always** define a **length** for your `CHAR` or `VARCHAR` parameters - if you don't, the length defaults to **1 character** - most of the time NOT what you want!

Answer (score 2):

How about the following?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AssignGradeToStudent 
    @ClassNumber char, 
    @Student int,
    @Grade char
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE Enrollment
    SET [Grade] = COALESCE(@Grade,[Grade])
    WHERE [Class Number] = @ClassNumber
       AND [Student] = @Student
END
GO
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really appreciate your help and I was able to solve this procedure with your help.  I tied in the differneces between what I had and what you had.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is riddled with issues.

Change the parameter from `@[Class Number]` to `@ClassNumber`

Remove the last comma after `@Grade char`

Your where clause seems incorrect, you might want to change it to

```
Where [Class Number] = @ClassNumber
AND [Student] = @Student
```

Comment: Thank you for your contribution Adriaan, even though you could've been a bit nicer with the, "This is riddler with issues". But that's okay.